# How to manipulate app from my own unity app? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I´ve got no code to show, I just wanted to know if you guys could guide me so I can begin my research to start my project. Well, imagine you have a videogame or an app on your computer. How could I control some components that belong to the app from another device. I mean, I want to create an app for mobile devices that allow me to control some components from a specific computer app. My app would be created on Unity. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Could you please give an example to clarify? Do you want to control a PC app from a mobile app?

Comment: Yes, that´s exactly what I want. Like, imagine you are playing GTA and you are driving a car, there is a radio in that car. What I want something like having a UI in the mobile app that represents the radio of that car, so I can change the volume and all that stuff.

Comment: You need to research for any Multiplayer service provider  like photoncloud/gamespark etc. It will helps you  to communicate real time between your apps. I assume that both app going to develop by you.

Comment: @Jasil Hi Jasil, there is the problem... I’m just going to develop one app, the one with the interface, so I need to get information from an external app.

Comment: I think what you are asking is not possible to implement with out other app developers support. you should need to get some API for integrating you functionality  :)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will keep trying :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating an app on your PC that receives messages from an app on your phone, then uses windows API hooks to fake key presses.

It's a really big and broad question you've asked, so it is hard to add too much more unless you are very specific.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for not being more specific... One question, where can I find info on how to recieve info in the pc app from the app that contains de info?

Comment: There are many different networking extensions for Unity, but I haven't ever really used them.  I use NodeJS to write servers, and there is an asset store package for free that handles NodeJS networking from within unity.